# Long polling to asp.net mvc app requires POST instead of GET ajax method. Why?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm duplicating a demo app used by steven sanderson's signalR demo in which he demonstrates long polling. The demo works, but the part that I (and others on my team) are scratching our head at is when we replace the ajax method to use a GET instead of a POST in the polling function.

When we use POST, all is good. The client submits a new chat. The server sets the new chat in the TaskCompletionSource member, and all clients that are polling the server for a new chat (via the longPoll()) method receive the new chat.

When I change the longPoll() js function to use a GET method, the server responds to one client. The next message is submitted, and the server responds to a different client--only one client each time, and in order.

Any ideas on why this is working this way?

```
public class ChatController : Controller
{
     static TaskCompletionSource<string> _nextMessage
       = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    //
    // GET: /Chat/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<string> longPoll()
    {
         return  await _nextMessage.Task;

    }


    public void PostMessage(string message)
    {
        _nextMessage.SetResult(message);
        _nextMessage = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".btn-submit").click(function () {

        //send chat message to server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/chat/PostMessage",
            data: {message: $("#txtMessage").val()}
        })

        //reset textbox
        $("#txtMessage").val("");

     });

    (function longPoll() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat/longPoll",
            success: function (message) {
                //when response is recieved, update list and call this function again
                $("<li>").text(message).appendTo("#messages");

            },
            error: function( jqXHR ,  textStatus,  errorThrown){
                console.log("error: " + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: longPoll
        });

    })();

});
```

html:

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>

Say something: <input type="text" id="txtMessage" />
           <button class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You should probably add `[HttpPost]` - something like that as an attribute for your `PostMessage` method.

Comment: Good idea. I did that just now for POST. But this won't work when I change the ajax method to GET, which is the goal.

Comment: is there a caching issue?

Comment: I don't think so because there is no response from the server on all clients except for one when I use GET.The connections remain open.

Answer (score -1):

Your post is send many times, this is bad.

For Chat Application, is better to use [AsyncController](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526099/Asynchronous-Controller-in-ASP-NET-MVC).

Use JavaScript function to control pooling (`setInterval` or `setTimeout`). 1s of time is good.

Comment: This is a long poll, which keeps an open connection to the server. The method you describe is a simple polling technique which is whole different scenario.

Comment: Fact. This is another scenario. My misunderstood.